# How to add toastr JS notification on application level in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using [toastr](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/) gem for my notifications. I am trying to add a toastr notification to my application whenever a method on my `application_controller.rb` is active.

```
rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

    def user_not_authorized
      toastr.info('You cannot access this page.', 'info')
      redirect_to contacts_path
    end
```

As you can see I tried to add `toastr`function on my controller, however this doesn't work. How can I show this toastr notification whenever this method hits or simply whenever a non-admin user access an unathorized page?

Answer (score 1):

To build on the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62094950/308731), this is what I did in my app. Added what I wanted to show to `flash` in the controller and then show the flash messages in `toastr`

I'm using the great `slim` extension there, add it with `gem 'slim-rails'` and save this file as `_messages.html.slim`, you can then include it in your layout file.

```
- flash.each do |name, msg|
  javascript:
    window.onload = function() {  
      var name = "#{name}";

      if (name == 'info' || name == 'notice') {
        toastr.info("#{msg}");
      }
      else if (name == 'success') {      
        toastr.success("#{msg}");
      } 
      else if (name == 'error') {      
        toastr.error("#{msg}");
      } 
      else {
        toastr.info("#{msg}");
      }        
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

`toastr` is a Javascript library and you can't use it within Ruby code.

However, if you want to show some kind of notifications to a user and define them in the context of a Rails controller, you can make use of [Rails Flash Notifications](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash).

In the `application_controller.rb` file:

```
rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

def user_not_authorized
  flash[:notice] = "You cannot access this page."
  redirect_to contacts_path
end
```

And somewhere in your HTML/ERB file, you would render the HTML elements for each one of the the flash notifications set in the controllers:

```
<html>
  <!-- <head/> -->
  <body>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: name %>
    <% end -%>

    <!-- more content -->
  </body>
</html>
```

You can consult more example of its usage in the link above.